# Finding the velocity of a mass in a spring system

Tags: proof-verification, classical-mechanics

I am given that a mass $m$ is connected to a spring such that when it is at position $x$ the force acting on it is $F=-kx^3$. The mass is then moved to position $x_0$ and released from rest.

What is the velocity at $x=0?$

My thoughts so far are as follows:

$$F=-kx^3=-\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{1}{4}kx^4\bigg)$$

So the potential $V$ is then $V=\frac{1}{4}kx^4.$

So then set $\frac{1}{4}kx_0^4=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ which then gives $v=\sqrt{\frac{kx_0^4}{2m}}$

Is this correct?

The next part of the question then asks me to find the coefficient of friction required to bring the mass to rest at $x=0$ given that the surface is now rough.

To do this I have set $$\frac{1}{4}kx_0^4=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\mu mgx_0$$

Then rearranging this I get $$\mu =\frac{kx_0^4-2mv^2}{4mgx_0}$$

Comment: That is perfectly fine!

Comment: @user Wait so is it correct or not?

Comment: it is TOTALLY correct.

Comment: @user Thank you. I have added another part to my question, could you check this too please?

Comment: that is ALSO correct.

Comment: @user For the second part should I not have set $v$ equal to $0$ since I'm looking for the coefficient of friction needed to bring the mass to rest?

Comment: you are right, you must!

Comment: @user So the correct answer would be $\mu = \frac{kx_0 ^4}{4mgx_0}$?

Comment: yes, I am sorry did not have notice.